# How can I see IP income from participating in league of legends tribunal?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any place where I can see how much IP I got from tribunal participation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every so often, they'll send you an email discussing how much IP you've earned from your cases. There's no actual record in-game that keeps track of where your IP is coming from.